# mkdir not setting permissions correctly

Tags: python, mkdir, mode, pathlib

I am trying to make a directory that has the "set group ID on execution" set
in Python

In the shell:

```
$ mkdir --mode 2775 mail
$ ls -ld mail
drwxrwsr-x 1 john john 0 May  3 08:34 mail
      ^
```

In Python I am using `pathlib.Path.mkdir`, and it seems there some bits for mode are not taken into account,
even when the `umask` is cleared:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

os.umask(0)
md = Path('mail')
md.mkdir(mode=0o2775)    

drwxrwxr-x 1 john john 0 May  3 08:35 mail
       ^
```

Is there some cut-off at nine bits that is not [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir)

Comment: Have you checked the bug tracker for similar bugs? That might be the quickest path to an explanation or workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, on non-Windows systems, `Path.mkdir` calls `os.mkdir` which in turn invokes the C system call `mkdirat`. That call's behavior is defined in terms of [`mkdir`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir), which, on Linux, documents the `mode` with:

> The argument mode specifies the permissions to use. It is modified by the process's umask in the usual way: the permissions of the created directory are `(mode & ~umask & 0777)`

Note that the permissions explicitly mask off all bits above `0777`; this is just how `mkdir` system calls behave on some OSes. You'll just have to `chmod` it after the fact.

Comment: So it is the underlying system call's limitation. Would be nice if that returned an error (that could be percolated to Python) instead of silently masking extra bits.

Answer (score 1):

`pathlib`'s `mkdir` essentially just calls [`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir). The documentation there includes the section:

> On some systems, mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current umask value is first masked out. If bits other than the last 9 (i.e. the last 3 digits of the octal representation of the mode) are set, their meaning is platform-dependent. On some platforms, they are ignored and you should call `chmod()` explicitly to set them.

So only the last 9 bits are guaranteed to be used.
You'll have to do (no need to set umask):

```
md.mkdir()
md.chmod(0o2775)
```

It would be better if `pathlib` would not silently ignore extra bits, but actually threw a ValueError.

Comment: Yes should have been nine bits, I edited my question.